# Visual Studio 2017 c++ - error project output 'Primary Output targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to port a current working project to other computer, both are using the latest Visual Studio version and the project uses opencv library.

I've got two projects:

- The project App, builds and works fine, I'm able to test it
  in debug and release modes.
- Setup project, to deploy the app ( which all work fine in the other
  machine).

The targeting platform is x64 and the configuration manager setup is:

[image]

When I'm trying to build the Setup Project I've got the error:

```
ERROR: File 'Apptest.exe' of project output 'Primary Output from Apptest(Active)' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
```

If my project is clearly setup targeting 64bits, anyone knows or have any clues why I'm getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: probably a compiler switch, specifically this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/arch-arm?view=vs-2017

Comment: You need to create a 64-bit setup project to properly deploy it.  Right now it is a 32-bit one, the default.  It is just a simple property of the Setup project that you can change with the Properties window, I forgot its exact name.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I found the property and I changed it to x64 platform, now it works, the option is in the Setup Project properties window ->TargetPlatform.